# SearchBar hangs on iphone but works fine on simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, uisearchbar

my app has around 200 UITableView rows, when i use simulator on xcode to filter data through UISearchBar, it filters and shows result instantly however, when i run my app in my iphone (iphone4, iOS 5.1.1), it hangs for couple of seconds before showing any search result. I'm using this code to filter data...

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{
[self.filteredData removeAllObjects];

if ([searchText length] > 0) {
    self.isSearching = YES;
    for (AClass *filteredData in self.allData) {
        NSRange titleResultRange = [filteredData.name rangeOfString:self.searchBar.text options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        if (titleResultRange.location != NSNotFound) {
            [self.filteredData addObject:filteredData];
        }
    }
}
else self.isSearching = NO;
[self.tableView reloadData];}
```

I believe my code is okay since it's working perfectly fine on the simulator, is there anything i need to do to make it work faster on iphone? 
btw, my iPhone is working perfectly fine,  i use other apps, they work fine for me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your device is taking longer than the simulator is due to the amount of memory available.  As a general rule, don't use the performance of your app in the simulator to judge your app's performance.

If you are filtering a very large data set in the way you describe, I would suggest using dispatch queues to perform your search instead of doing it all in the main queue.  You can read about them here:  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html

In case you don't want to read the entire documentation, here's an example of what this would look like with your code.

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{
    [self.filteredData removeAllObjects];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        if ([searchText length] > 0) {
            self.isSearching = YES;
            for (AClass *filteredData in self.allData) {
                NSRange titleResultRange = [filteredData.name rangeOfString:self.searchBar.text options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
                if (titleResultRange.location != NSNotFound) {
                    [self.filteredData addObject:filteredData];
                }
            }
        }
        else self.isSearching = NO;
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        });
    });
}
```

Please note that the example I am giving you is not thread safe... you will need to make sure that only one search is being performed at any given time or this code will crash, since the same array will be referenced across multiple queues.  If you need more assistance, leave a comment and I'll try to get to it.